# C# accept server certificate using Asp.Net AddHttpClient

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, dependency-injection, webapi

I want to request a third party server from my Asp.Net Web-Api and am using `AddHttpClient` to inject the `HttpClient` but I´m getting **Http-Code 403 Forbidden**. Usally I would use the following line to accept the certifiacte:

```
        var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
        handler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
        handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };

        Log.Trace("Create HttpClient");
        using var client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

But as I use this line I cannot pass a constructor parameter:

```
        services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client =>
        {
            client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(_serverURI);
        });
```

I know `.AddHttpClientHandler` but this is not working like I want it to. Someone suggest a solution to inject the `HttpClientHandler`?

Comment: That is not going to fix your error anyway. A 403 indicates you are failing authentication, which is unrelated to ignoring the server certificate using `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` which you **really** shouldn't do

Comment: Yes some time later I´ve found out while refactring the complete logic to DI I´ve deletefactored the authentication process ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure the message handler by chaining the method `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` [microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.configureprimaryhttpmessagehandler?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0):

```
services.AddHttpClient<IMyService, MyService>(client =>
{
     client.BaseAddress = new System.Uri(_serverURI);
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
     return new HttpClientHandler
     {
        ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Manual,
        ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback =
            (httpRequestMessage, cert, cetChain, policyErrors) =>
            {
                return true;
            }
     };
});
```